# Custom Sort of SelectOption

Tags: visualforce, picklist, selectoption

I have a scenario in which i need to display the country data in below format:

United States

Canada

{Alphabetical Ascending sort of the remaining countries}

The data is coming from custom table and the list is bound to selectOption.

Comment: Please do not put comments like "its urgent" or similar demands in your question,. If it was truly urgent you could have taken the time to learn how to [Ask] a question. SFSE is not here to write your code for you so what have you tried so far. `The most basic answer is populate the select option in the order you want the items to display.`

Comment: Additionally look into the Comparable interface to create a sorted list per your specifications to populate the selectOption

Comment: I would use a SOQL `order by` and special case those 2.

Comment: @KeithC - good call since it was stated as alphabetical sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[list.sort()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_lists_sorting.htm) method is used to sort picklist values

```
  <apex:selectList value="{!country}" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Countries}" />
   </apex:selectList>
```

---

```
 public List<SelectOption> getCountries(){
    optionsCountryMainList = new list<SelectOption>();
    optionsCountrySubList = new list<SelectOption>();

    optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('', '-- Select Country --', true)); 

    optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('USA','USA'));
    optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','CANADA'));

    for(Country__c country : [SELECT Id, Name From Country__c]){
        if(country.Name !='USA' && country.Name !='CANADA')
        optionsCountrySubList.add(new SelectOption(country.Name, country.Name));
    }


    optionsCountrySubList.sort();  
    optionsCountryMainList.addAll(optionsCountrySubList);
    return optionsCountryMainList;
}
```

---

Or Use Order By in SOQL

```
public List<SelectOption> getCountries(){
        optionsCountryMainList = new list<SelectOption>();
        optionsCountrySubList = new list<SelectOption>();

        optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('', '-- Select Country --', true)); 

        optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('USA','USA'));
        optionsCountryMainList.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','CANADA'));

        for(Country__c country : [SELECT Id, Name From Country__c order by Name]){
            if(country.Name !='USA' && country.Name !='CANADA')
            optionsCountrySubList.add(new SelectOption(country.Name, country.Name));
        }

        optionsCountryMainList.addAll(optionsCountrySubList);
        return optionsCountryMainList;
    }
```

Comment: Good to know - documentation does not say that `SelectOption` implements `Comparable` but I guess as this work it does... But this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Exactly my thought, +1. I'd also add to the `getCountries()` method: `optionsCountry.add(new SelectOption('USA', 'USA'));` and `optionsCountry.add(new SelectOption('Canada', 'Canada'));` above the `for` loop as he wants these displayed first.